# Solving Riccati ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have recently started studying the methods behind solving different types of differential equations and have made it to Bernoulli with no problems thus far. However, as I was investigating Riccati ODEs I noticed that many sources are inconsistent with the substitution that is used to reduce a Riccati equation to Bernoulli. I would like to pose the following ODE:

$$
y' = y^2 -xy +1 
$$

If you know any good resources to use to attain a better understanding of this type of equation please let me know. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3):

As far es I know the name "Ricatti equation" $($for example see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html), equation $(4)$$)$ in the context of differential equations refers to specific type of non-linear first order DEs. To be precise in general to equations of the form

> $$y'+p(x)y+q(x)y^2=r(x)\tag1$$

which are **only** solvable for the case that you know one particular solution $y_1(x)$. The general solution can be obtained by making the substitution

$$y=y_1(x)+v(x)\tag2$$

Plugging this new form into the original equation leads to

$$\begin{align}
(y_1+v)'+p(x)(y_1+v)+q(x)(y_1+v)^2&=r(x)\\
y_1'+v'+p(x)y_1+p(x)v+q(x)y_1^2+q(x)v^2+2q(x)v&=r(x)\\
v'+(2q(x)y_1+p(x))v+q(x)v^2+\underbrace{[y_1'+p(x)y_1+q(x)y_1^2-r(x)]}_{=0}&=0
\end{align}$$

where the term within the braces vanishs since $y_1$ - as a particular solution to $(1)$ - fulfills the given DE. From hereon we are left with the equation

> $$v'+(2q(x)y_1+p(x))v+q(x)v^2=0$$

which is just a Bernoulli equation in $v$. Solving this one and recombining with the particular solution as stated in $(2)$ yields to the general solution.

---

Lets focus on your given DE.

$$y'+xy-y^2=1\tag{I}$$

It is not hard to see that a particular solution would be $y_1(x)=x$. By using the ansatz as provided before we will consider the general solution to be of the type

$$y=y_1(x)+v(x)\Rightarrow y=x+v(x)$$

By plugging this within $($I$)$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}
(x+v(x))'+x(x+v(x))-(x+v(x))^2&=1\\
1+v'(x)+x^2+xv(x)-x^2-v^2(x)-2xv(x)&=1\\
v'(x)-xv(x)-v^2(x)&=0\\
\Leftrightarrow -\frac{v'(x)}{v^2(x)}+\frac{x}{v(x)}+1&=0
\end{align}$$

This DE is now of Bernoulli type and can be solved by considering the substitution $z=\frac1{v(x)}$ which leads to $z'=-\frac{v'(x)}{v^2(x)}$ and thus $z'+xz+1=0$. The general solution to this ODE is given by

$$z(x) = c_1 e^{-x^2/2} - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2} e^{-x^2/2} \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac x{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

which can be obtained by Separation of Variables and Variation of Variables respectively. What is left now are the resubstitutions. So we get for $v(x)$

$$v(x)=\frac1{z}\Leftrightarrow v(x)=\frac1{c_1 e^{-x^2/2} - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2} e^{-x^2/2} \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac x{\sqrt{2}}\right)}=\frac{e^{x^2/2}}{c_1 - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2} \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac x{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$

and so finally for the general solution

$$y=y_1(x)+v(x)=x+\frac{e^{x^2/2}}{c_1 - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2} \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac x{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me- Given  a particular solution $y_1(x)$, on what basis we can choose the general form like $y(x)=y_1(x)+v(x)$ ? why not as $y(x)=y_1(x)v(x)$

Comment: @math Try to plug in $y(x)=y_1(x)v(x)$. It won't yield anything helpful at all, where on the other side the ansatz $y(x)=y_1(x)+v(x)$ reduces the problem to solving a Bernoulli equation, which is doable. In addition, if you have two solution of *any* (homogeneous) DE, any linear combination of those two will also be a solution (take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246643/why-is-a-linear-combination-of-solutions-also-a-solution) for further input).

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I understand that Linear comb point. Just one more- It is a first order DE, then it should not have two solutions ? May be I need to read more.

Comment: @math It has one *general* solution but many *particular* solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$y' = y^2 -xy +1$$
Here is how to reduce it to Bernouilli's equation
$$(y-x)'=y(y-x)$$
$$\frac {d(y-x)}{dx}=y(y-x)$$
$$\frac {d(y-x)}{dx}=(y-x+x)(y-x)$$
Substitute $z=y-x$
$$z'=(z+x)z \implies z'=zx+z^2$$
This is Bernouilli's equation ( see mrtaurho' s complete answer for the solution ...)

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is to consider $u=e^{-Y}$ where $Y=\int y\,dx$, or $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$, so that $u'=-e^{-Y}y$ and $$u''=e^{-Y}(y^2-y')=e^{-Y}(xy-1)=-xu'-u$$
This equation in particular can now be integrated once to
$$
u'+xu=C
$$
and this now is a first order linear ODE.